# Using d3.js with XML

Tags: javascript, xml, d3.js

I want to bind data from and XML document into and HTML using d3.js. Currently I have XML like this:

```
<data>
<fields>Unique Terms</fields>
    <term>Roof</term>
    <term>Snow</term>
    <term>Chains</term>
    <term>Bars</term>
    <term>Seat</term>
<fields>Clicks</fields>
    <clicks>135</clicks>
    <clicks>09</clicks>
    <clicks>4379</clicks>
    <clicks>39</clicks>
    <clicks>466</clicks>
<fields>Impressions</fields>
</data>
```

And my d3.js script like this:

```
d3.xml("values.xml", "application/xml", function(xml) {

    var fieldNames = d3.select(xml).selectAll("fields")[0];
    var termNames = d3.select(xml).selectAll("term")[0];

    d3.select('.container')
        .selectAll('div')
        .data(fieldNames)
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.textContent;
        })

    d3.select('.container')
        .selectAll('div')
        .data(termNames)
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.textContent;
        })

});
```

Frustratingly it shows the fields textcontent but not the nested 'term' content. Anybody know what's up?

Comment: What's the intended outcome?  Your "terms" aren't nested in your "fields" in your data file, or in your d3.  Currently when you `selectAll('div')` the second time, you're just re-selecting the elements you created in your previous block.  Since none of those are new elements, your `.enter()` selection is empty.

Comment: How are you trying to display them?  In a nested hierarchy?  Or as a simple list of two arrays?